# using sitemap path with treeview

Tags: asp.net

i have inserted a sitemap data source + treeview control, written up my sitemap file, all the folder/file names are correct, yet, treeview is not reading directly from the sitemap file. Any suggestions?

sitemap code is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >

    <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home"  description="">
        <siteMapNode url="~/about2.aspx" title="About"  description="" >
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="~/menu.aspx" title="Menu" description="">
            <siteMapNode url="~/starters.aspx" title="Starters" description=""/>
            <siteMapNode url="~/mains.aspx" title="Mains" description=""/>
            <siteMapNode url="~/desserts.aspx" title="Desserts" description=""/>
            <siteMapNode url="~/drinks.aspx" title="Drinks" description=""/>
            <siteMapNode url="~/specials.aspx" title="Specials" description=""/>
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="~/contact.aspx" title="Contact" description="">
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="~/findus.aspx" title="Find Us" description="">
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="~/reviews.aspx" title="Reviews" description="">
        </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

could it be that the webforms i want the sitemap to work with are added to the root of the folder, and not in a folder? Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

source code for asp.net/html.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="sitemap.aspx.vb" Inherits="sitemap" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
        <br />

    </div>
    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
    </asp:TreeView>
    </form>
</body>
</html
```

>

Answer (score 0):

Came across this searching for something else. Your SiteMapDataSource has no "SiteMapProvider" specified. How does it know which map to use?

This has to be specified in web.config in the systen.web sections

```
    <siteMap defaultProvider="secure" enabled="true">
       <providers>
         <add name="mapname" description="my site map" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="filename.sitemap" />
       </providers>
     </siteMap>
```

So you should set SiteMapProvider="mapname"